# Is there a way to use quaternions for only 2d rotations?

Tags: ios, rotation, quaternions

I have an iPhone app which should get every rotation avoiding Gimbal Lock, and I understood that the solution could be using quaternions or rotation matrix.

However, I find difficult to understand how can I use quaternions for 2d rotation instead of using 3d rotation.

Answer (score 2):

From algorithmic point of view you can start from [understanding quaternions](http://www.essentialmath.com/GDC2013/GDC13_quaternions_final.pdf). However, you can see how to [convert 3D rotation to 2D rotation](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/348097/convert-3d-rotation-to-2d-rotation.html). Finally, you can see how to include quaternions in ios graphics using [GLKQuaternion Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKQuaternion/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: What I should find is something that permit me to get in every time T the exact degrees of every rotation axis. How should I use Quaternions for it?